# Invalid block tag on line 3: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I have my main home template, that I would like to extend one of two sets of headers from but I am getting an error that seems to indicate the else does not work in this statement. I also tried changing to an elif for when user is not logged in and the elif was shown as undefined. These are the first lines of code in the file so there aren't other things loaded prior to these either. The problem code:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% extends "main/header.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "landing/header.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Is the extend not allowed to be conditionally added? If so is there a correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

`include` and `extends` do not work the same way.

a way to make conditional use of `extends` is to use the built-in filter `yesno`

```
{% extends request.user.is_authenticated|yesno:'main/header.html,landing/header.html' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

## you can use include in this case

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% include "main/header.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% include "landing/header.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work as per [user2354992](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2354992/user2354992).

But if someone wants to set a condition based on some value then it's not work in this case you need to try this.

You can pass the template name from the view like this.

```
if user.user_type == 10:
    context['template_name'] = "main/header.html"
else:
    context['template_name'] = "landing/header.html"
```

and use this context variable like this in the template.

```
{% extends base_template %}
```

see the document for reference

[docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#extends)